# Как отменить переход на следующую ViewController при неверных введенных данных

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Есть 2 ViewController: основная и userInfo, на основной 2 TextField, логин и пароль, как блокировать переход на userInfo если одно из повей введенно не правильно?
Пока есть только это:

```
- (IBAction)enterUserInfo:(UIButton *)sender {

if ([self.cardNumber.text isEqual: @"12345"] && [self.password.text isEqual: @"12345"]) {

} else {
    UIAlertView *loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ошибка"
                                                    message:@"Введены неверные данные"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [loginAlert show];


}

NSLog(@"Card nuber = %@, password = %@", self.cardNumber.text, self.password.text);
```

}

Что нужно дописать чтобы прервать связь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если переход делается через segue то надо его убрать а в вашем коде в условии если пароль и логин верны добавить строки:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboard bundle:nil];
UserInfoViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserInfo"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

где viewController это контроллер того класса который нужно отобразить

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!)

Comment: Есть же метод canPerformSegue, не обязательно убирать